# Domain Driven Design which tables is a repository allowed to access

Tags: spring-data-jpa, architecture, repository, domain-driven-design

I am wondering if a repository that persists aggregate A with several entities, values objects, ... is 'allowed' to access tables that hold aggregate B. An example would be the following.

My system is a webshop that holds several products. `Product` is an aggregate root so I have a `ProductRepository`. Then a single `Order` is also an aggregate root with its repository `OrderRepository`. Let's say the `Order` aggregate does include all `OrderLineItems`:

Now my customer demands a section in the webshop that shows products that have never been purchased. In SQL this would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM OrderLineItems o WHERE o.productId = p.id
)
```

Would this query be allowed for `ProductRepository` since it only returns `Products` or is `ProductRepository` not allowed to use this query since it accesses data of another aggregate?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use a CQRS-like approach for this kind of problem. Use DDD Aggregates "only" for the "write" side, same thing for the Repository classes.

Build Materialized Views and specific Query Models for stuff that doesn't mutate the state, like the unsold products query you have.

For example, you could use Repositories when mutating the state (the "write" side), for example when you're persisting an Order.

When you have to query for unsold products instead, you could have a specific Query Handler that runs a direct query to the db (maybe using a lightweight library like Dapper).

Answer (score 1):

- It is certainly allowed
- I probably wouldn't choose to add it to the `ProductRepository` myself

A really important thing to notice is that what we are generating here is a *report*, which is to say we are not creating a local copy of the information because we intend to change that information.

The concern of the domain model is domain *dynamics*, which is to say the rules governing how our domain data changes over time.  If we're not going to change the data, then maybe we don't need the model?

So you might end up with a facade that kind of looks like a repository, but instead of returning an domain entity/aggregate root instead returns just the raw data that you will send over the network (for example, just returning the html, csv, or json that you need directly).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that it is allowed but may not be best practice. My worry was exactly that my repository holds several methods that are solely related to the query needs of the frontend. What I am still interested in is what your proposed solution would be? I was thinking about CQRS to separate the dynamics from the static view.